# Can't reply to own comments in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

In the chat, one can link one's next message as a reply to another message. This way, the thread is easy to follow, especially when replying to a message that is further up the page.

Why can't one link to one's own previous message? If I posted something yesterday, and then want to comment on it, the option is not available to me.

Isn't this a useful feature that would improve the chat experience?

Comment: On-point comment that I disagree with: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87796/block-the-ability-to-manually-ping-oneself-in-chat/87885#comment217411_87885

Comment: Declined on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/allow-me-to-reply-to-myself-on-chat

Comment: @balpha, You commented on MSO that you don't see a use case for this feature, but apparently, many users in multiple contexts organically have determined differently. What is the downside to removing this restriction? Wouldn't the code actually be simpler with it removed?

Comment: @balpha pleeeeeeaassssseeeee

Answer (score 8):

You can do it, but it's not exposed in the UI (and I, too, wish it were).  Here's the workaround:

Click on your own message over on the left (where you go for edit, delete, etc) and grab the URL for the permalink.  You'll see something like this:

> http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10185532#10185532

Take the part from # to the end, delete the rest, and replace the # with a :, like this:

> :10185532 blah blah blah...

Your reply (blah blah blah... above) will show up as a reply to your previous message.

Because Chat doesn't really know how this happened, you will also get a ping alerting you to your new reply.